# Compiling a list of all colonies/neighborhoods for a particular city

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want a list of locations (coordinates) for all possible colonies/neighborhoods of some Indian cities. Take for example Delhi. Can this data be obtained with the Places API?

The only thing that comes to my mind is to use a query like -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=28.540346,77.210026&radius=500&types=administrative_area_level_1|administrative_area_level_2|administrative_area_level_3|locality|neighborhood|street_address|sublocality|sublocality_level_4|sublocality_level_5|sublocality_level_3|sublocality_level_2|sublocality_level_1|subpremise&sensor=false&key=MYKEY
```

and then keep changing the radius by 500 till the whole city is covered.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This use of the Google Places API is not permitted as described in Sec 10.1.3 of the Google Maps/Google Earth API Terms of Service: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given how often you would need to do this for your map, since caching that data goes against the terms of service, this is not a great approach. If you map gets any decent usage, you'll rapidly hit your quota. Plus you're only get center points of the colonies/neighborhoods. I'd recommend trying to find another source of that data you can download. The Places API was not designed with this in mind.